# Will get the pages indexed via analytics API?

Tags: api, indexed

I am using analytics API https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data to get the below mentioned metrics,

```
$metrics     = array("sessions","avgSessionDuration","bounceRate","Pageviews","percentNewSessions","users","pageviewsPerSession","newUsers");
```

Can I get the pages indexed data thorugh this API? I want the number of pages indexed, also the pages list which indexed in google. 
If possible via analytics API, please share me the metrics name to get the indexed pages data.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics does not provide information about indexed pages. You will need to use the [Google Search Console API](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/prereqs) instead.